# How to use column names as x axis values in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I've started learning matplotlib and I've been struggling with a task for a while now. I have a dataframe that looks something like the one below. I would like to plot this with the years as x-axis values and with each city (i.e. each row) as it's own plot. Seemingly easy task (literally one click in Excel) but I still haven't found a working way to do it. Every tutorial with similar dataframes seems to have the axes swapped (years in one column).

| City | 1990 | 1991 | ... | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| city1 | 0 | 2 | ... | 5 | 7 |
| city2 | 0 | 1 | ... | -5 | -8 |
| city3 | 0 | -5 | ... | -17 | -30 |

The closest I've gotten is by using 2 for-loops to iterate through the rows and years and appending every value to a list (toPlot is my dataframe):

```
years = range(1990,2021)

for rowIndex in range(0,9):
    datapoints = []
    for year in years:
        datapoints.append(toPlot.loc[rowIndex, year])
    plt.plot(years,datapoints)
```

It works as expected for 2 rows, but when it reaches rowIndex = 2, for some reason it raises a KeyError. So out of my 9 rows, only two get plotted.
[as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXxez.png)

However, I also need to get the city names in a legend and I don't know if it's possible with my approach.

How would I best tackle this and plot the values correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only need to transpose your data. If you have a Dataframe, by default Matplotlib will put on x-axis the index of the DataFrame, and will plot every column separately.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [{'City': 'city1', '1990': 0, '1991': 2, '2019': 5, '2020': 7},
 {'City': 'city2', '1990': 0, '1991': 1, '2019': -5, '2020': -8},
 {'City': 'city3',  '1990': 0,  '1991': -5, '2019': -17,  '2020': -30}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)\
    .set_index('City')\
    .T\
    .rename(pd.to_numeric)

df.plot(subplots=True)
```

[image: cities]